# Windows Phone GetUserStoreForApplication exception when clossing aplication

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-8

I had done a small application. I am interested to save some data when user click back and close the Applicaiton.

This is classic application even Application will be closed.

```
private void Application_Closing
{

   objSaveData = null;
}
```

....

```
public class objSaveData
{
    ~objSaveData
    {
      try
      { 
         IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
      }
      catch
      {
      }
    }
}
```

The Emulator returns me an error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think it's a problem from the destructor of my object, because it is inovked sometime by the garbage collector

Comment: Empty catch blocks are evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple:

```
private void Application_Closing
{
   //objSaveData = null;  // no use
   IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
   ... use it to save something
}

public class objSaveData
{
// destructors are called in an unpredictable fashion, usually too late. 
//    ~objSaveData
//    {
//      try
//      { 
//         IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
//      }
// empty catch blocks hide errors, don't do this
//      catch
//      {
//      }
//    }
}
```

Comment: Good. The lesson here is that in an event-driven GUI, use events.

Answer (score 1):

From Msdn can be theese problems:

**SecurityException**

Sufficient isolated storage permissions have not been granted.

**IsolatedStorageException**

An isolated storage location cannot be initialized.
-or-

The application identity of the caller cannot be determined, because the ActivationContext property returned null.

-or-
The permissions for the application domain cannot be determined.

Answer (score 1):

The exception might be caused because you don't explicitly dispose the store try this code:

```
  try
  { 
     using ( IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication() ){
     }
  }
  catch
  {
  }
```

IsolatedStorage sometimes behaves in very unusual ways if all connections are not closed properly.

Comment: I think it's a problem from the destructor of my object, because it is inovked sometime by the garbage collector

Comment: That is possible – the destructor might be called too late, maybe? What about implementing IDisposable's Dispose method and call objSaveData.Dispose() before setting it to null?